# bloginfo() vs get_option?

Tags: functions, options, bloginfo

What's the difference between:

`bloginfo('name');`

vs

`get_option('blogname');`

The parameter is just an example, but I see no differences in terms displaying what I want.

Are there any particular differences? Or are they just for semantic reasons.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two functions output exactly the same thing.

From the [Codex entry for `get_bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo):

> 'name' - Returns the "Site Title" set in Settings > General. This data is retrieved from the "blogname" record in the wp_options table.

From [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L519):

```
case 'name':
default:
    $output = get_option('blogname');
```

Neither `get_bloginfo()` nor `bloginfo()` do any sort of sanitization or escaping; so both `get_bloginfo( 'name' )` and `get_option( 'blogname' )` return exactly the same value.

Comment: Thanks, that was simple. I should start looking more into the source code from now (should have done that first before asking, sorry).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `bloginfo` will output value ;) If you want to get the value, you should use `get_bloginfo`.

`get_bloginfo` takes one param from predefined set (You can find all possible values here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo). Only part of these values are values of options (in such case `bloginfo` returns value of that option).

> Returns information about your site which can then be used elsewhere
>   in your PHP code. This function, as well as bloginfo(), can also be
>   used to display your site information anywhere within a template file.

On the other hand, `get_option` can be used to retrieve value of any option stored in options table.

> A safe way of getting values for a named option from the options
>   database table. If the desired option does not exist, or no value is
>   associated with it, FALSE will be returned.

Comment: Noted, thanks. I actually knew about this. Didn't realize what I asked could be so easily misunderstood, sorry. The ticked answer was what I was asking for.

Comment: "The parameter is just an example" - I think that was the reason of misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

**bloginfo**

Displays information about your site, mostly gathered from the information you supply in your User Profile and General Settings WordPress Administration Screens. It can be used anywhere within a template file. This always prints a result to the browser. If you need the values for use in PHP, use

`get_bloginfo()`.

Where as `get_option()` is far different from that, you can get any option from the `options.php` the link for the `options.php` is `http:yoursite/wp-admin/options.php` this  display all the fields. you can get the value from 
`$field_val = get_option('name_of_field');`. For more about get_option refer [codex get_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)